# Why does linux-image-virtual depend on a generic kernel now?

Tags: server, kernel, virtualization, metapackages

The [linux-image-virtual](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-image-virtual&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all) metapackage has historically provided a kernel that is specifically designed for use in virtual machines:

- Ubuntu 8.04: linux-image-2.6.24-32-virtual
- Ubuntu 10.04: linux-image-2.6.32-44-virtual
- Ubuntu 11.10: linux-image-3.0.0-26-virtual
- Ubuntu 12.04: linux-image-3.2.0-32-virtual

Apparently, this has now changed:

- Ubuntu 12.10: linux-image-3.5.0-17-*generic*

What's the explanation? Is this still the correct kernel to use in a virtual machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lower code maintenance requirements.  the generic kernel now has the bits and bobs from the virtual kernel, and is bright enough to know when it should or should not use them.

This Is A Feature, Not A Bug :)