# linux-image-virtual packages empty in 14.04 trusty?

Tags: 14.04, package-management, kernel

I can't seem to get a linux-virtual kernel (for VMs) installed in trusty. The packages install perfectly fine, but they simply are empty, without anything except changelog and copyright files in usr/share/doc.

What's the proper procedure to install -virtual kernel on Ubuntu 14.04 trusty? Or is the whole thing deprecated now?

Thanks

For reference:

```
root@s2:/boot/grub# dpkg -L linux-virtual
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/linux-virtual
/usr/share/doc/linux-virtual/copyright
/usr/share/doc/linux-virtual/changelog.gz
root@s2:/boot/grub# dpkg -L linux-image-virtual
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/linux-image-virtual
/usr/share/doc/linux-image-virtual/copyright
/usr/share/doc/linux-image-virtual/changelog.gz
root@s2:/boot/grub# dpkg -L linux-image-extra-virtual
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/linux-image-extra-virtual
/usr/share/doc/linux-image-extra-virtual/copyright
/usr/share/doc/linux-image-extra-virtual/changelog.gz
root@s2:/boot/grub# dpkg -L linux-headers-virtual
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/linux-headers-virtual
/usr/share/doc/linux-headers-virtual/copyright
/usr/share/doc/linux-headers-virtual/changelog.gz
root@s2:/boot/grub# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `linux-image-*` packages that *don't* contain a kernel version number in their name are [metapackages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages) (see also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66257/what-is-the-difference-between-a-meta-package-and-a-package)). They work by providing no software directly, but instead always declaring the latest stable kernel provided for your Ubuntu release as a [dependency](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware#Package_Dependencies). ([Here's some more information on what dependencies are in general.](https://askubuntu.com/a/361747/22949))

This [causes new kernels to be installed automatically when they are available](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages#Kernel_Metapackages) (and does so without removing older kernels, so you can boot with an older kernel if something is broken for you in the newer one).

**With all that said**, the kernels `linux-image-virtual` causes to be installed [*are (currently) the same ones as with `linux-image-generic`.*](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linux-image-virtual) That is, in recent releases such as 14.04, Ubuntu no longer provides separate kernels for VMs. (But `linux-image-virtual` still gives you a kernel and causes updated kernels to be installed; you don't have to install any other metapackage to make that happen.) [Ubuntu 12.04 *does* have separate virtual kernel packages.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/linux-image-virtual)

**There *is* still a difference** between `linux-image-generic` and `linux-image-virtual`, and that is that `linux-image-generic` [pulls in some extra kernel modules](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linux-image-generic) that may be considered nonessential, by depending not only on the latest `linux-image-<VERSION>-generic` package, but also the latest `linux-image-extra-<VERSION>-generic` package. In contrast, `linux-image-virtual` depends on `linux-image-<VERSION>-generic` but *not* on `linux-image-extra-<VERSION>-generic`.

This fulfills (at least part of) the goal of having "the virtual machine kernel" be more lightweight.

Considering this, you might be confused by how [a `linux-image-extra-virtual` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/linux-image-extra-virtual) still exists, even in Ubuntu 14.04. This works simply by declaring the `linux-image-generic` metapackage as a dependency. Back when `linux-image-extra-virtual` depended on actual `linux-image-extra-<VERSION>-virtual` module-providing packages (i.e., back when such packages existed, such as in 12.04), it installed what was then a separate virtual kernel, plus the extra modules. Now there's no separate virtual kernel, so all `linux-image-extra-virtual` needs to do is install the extra modules, which is achieved by making sure `linux-image-generic` is installed.

`linux-image-extra-virtual` is actually a [transitional package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20377/what-exact-purpose-have-transitional-packages) in recent Ubuntu releases; it really only exists anymore so that old systems (e.g., 12.04) with `linux-image-extra-virtual` have the necessary packages installed after being upgraded to newer systems (e.g., 14.04).

Sources:

- Embedded links to entries in the http://packages.ubuntu.com database.
- [Comment 1 for bug 1222278](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debian-installer/+bug/1222278/comments/1) by [Adam Conrad](https://launchpad.net/~adconrad), explaining the current difference between the `-generic` and `-virtual` kernel metapackages.

There's a lot of documentation that hasn't been updated to reflect that `linux-image-virtual` and `linux-image-generic` provide the same kernels, in recent Ubuntu releases, which is why I've provided links to `packages.ubuntu.com` to show the dependency relationships explicitly. (There's a slight bit of information [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213848/why-does-linux-image-virtual-depend-on-a-generic-kernel-now). Somewhere there are Ubuntu or Debian release notes that explicitly address this in more detail, I think.)

> Or is the whole thing deprecated now?

That may be considered an accurate description of what has happened. The key point, though, is that this is not related to there being no actual kernel files provided directly by `linux-image-virtual`; the `linux-image-generic` metapackage doesn't provide them directly either.

Comment: I guess I probably worded my question a bit imprecise, yet your answer probably answers *all* questions related to the virtual images in ubuntu 14.04. Thanks a lot.

Comment: So - if I'm understanding you correctly, in 15.04 after sudo apt-get install linux-virtual (or linux-image-virtual) then uname -a will still report "-generic" and /boot will contain only files named *-generic and none named *-virtual?  Geez I wish that web pages all over the place would be updated ... thanks for your answer here!