# How do I switch from linux-generic to linux-virtual?

Tags: apt, kernel

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 in a VM, and want to switch from the linux-generic kernel to the linux-virtual kernel. What are the commands to run? I have installed linux-virtual...

apt-get install linux-virtual

Whats next?

Answer (score 7):

No need to install `linux-virtual` anymore because it has the same dependencies as `linux-generic` except the package `linux-firmware` (compare these: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/linux-virtual, http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/linux-generic). Also, see the answer here [linux-image-virtual packages empty in 14.04 trusty?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503020/linux-image-virtual-packages-empty-in-14-04-trusty). But if you want to use it so that you have less packages installed then do this:

- `sudo apt-get install linux-virtual` (you've already done that)
- `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge linux-generic`
- `sudo apt-get remove --purge linux-firmware`
- `sudo update-grub`

*The main packages `linux-image-VERSION-generic` and `linux-headers-VERSION-generic` will be the same.*

Answer (score 3):

Depends on which host you are running your VM, you should maybe folow this MS article for Hyper-V:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531029.aspx

This enables the possibility to generate an VSS-Snapshot for the Backupsoftware.

Most important are these packages:

```
apt-get install linux-tools-virtual linux-cloud-tools-virtual
```

Comment: This solved the replications problem!

Comment: Please run after installing:     update-initramfs -u